# Loop through all possible options of a Dropdown-field

Tags: field, forloop, loop

I'm currently trying to create a for-loop that loops through all options of a dropdown field created in Craft.

I have a field called "Season", with the possible options to choose from being "2015/16" and "2016/17". What I'm trying to do now is to create a loop that would loop as many times as there are options available in that field.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
{% for option in fields.season %}
    ...code...
{% endfor %}`
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within Craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% for option in entry.dropdownFieldHandle.options %}
    <li>{{ option }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

That should be it :)

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionname') %}
  {% for option in entry.dropdownFieldHandle.options %}
    <li>{{ option }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Use the above if it is only one page

```
{% set myArray = [] %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionname') %}
  {% for option in entry.dropdownFieldHandle.options %}
        {% set value = option %}

        {% set myArray = myArray|merge([value]) %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And loop over that variable , better to load 1 variable as array if you need it over multiple pages. Just make sure all pages have access to this variable (or create a macro for it)

Comment: also if you want the fields in general use the following:

`{% set dropdown = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('season') %}

{% for option in dropdown.options %}
 {{ option }}
{% endif %}`

Comment: I'd guess you meant the last `{% endif %}` to be a `{% endfor %}`, but even then craft gives me the error that there is no scope called "options".

Comment: I edited my answers, one of the solutions should work.

Comment: Your first code snipped does not produce any output at all for me. The second does, but outputs every season as often as there are entries in the section I chose for `'sectionname'` instead of just once as required. Still appreciated :)

Comment: I got it solved by just limiting the `for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionname')` to 1 by appending `.limit(1)`